# jquery: loading a new page when refreshing the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open a new page when i reload the current page. So i was looked into some functions like **.unload()** and **.bind()** I have created this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZjcG/) using **bind()** and i don't know what should be added to make it reload a new page. thank you.

Here is what i tried for reloading of the current page itself:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){

     return 'lets reload';

    $(window).reload;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 116) {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            return "Do you really want to refresh the page?";
        }
    }
}, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
Press F5
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it will only work if user presses F5 key, if user clicks on refresh button it will not work, and that's impossible to track I think.

Comment: will you please explain this with fiddle. Thank you.